# How to extract lines within a range from a large textfile

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a SQL dump which is several GB in size. I'd like to extract several thousand lines, but really an arbitrary number of contiguous lines from the file to another so that I can run it in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

### There are a number of approaches

#### AWK

I first used the command line [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) utility to rip out lines, which I found the numbers for using vim

```
cat large-file.sql | \
    awk '{if (NR>=14054874) print}' | \
    awk '{if (NR <=2224) print}' > large-file-portion.dump.sql
```

the second number was found because chaining conditions with `&&` caused awk to do nothing.

To turn on line numbers in vim I ran the following

```
vi large-file.sql
:set number
/token that you are looking for/
:q!
```

#### Head | tail

Most of the other answers I found were using [head](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head) or [tail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) commands in isolation and did not represent a range of a file. I managed to combine them in the following arrangement.

```
cat large-file.sql | head -n 14053098 | tail -n 2224 > large-file-portion.dump.sql
```

Using the [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) utility I was able to find the best performing solution based on maximum resident set size & time

#### Performance

awk solution

```
real       162.66
user         0.23
sys          1.74
806912  maximum resident set size
     0  average shared memory size
     0  average unshared data size
     0  average unshared stack size
   208  page reclaims
     0  page faults
     0  swaps
     0  block input operations
     0  block output operations
     0  messages sent
     0  messages received
     0  signals received
172238  voluntary context switches
  3155  involuntary context switches
```

head | tail solution

```
real       136.77
user         0.22
sys          1.68
811008  maximum resident set size
     0  average shared memory size
     0  average unshared data size
     0  average unshared stack size
   209  page reclaims
     0  page faults
     0  swaps
     0  block input operations
     0  block output operations
     0  messages sent
     0  messages received
     0  signals received
159381  voluntary context switches
 22392  involuntary context switches
```

Hopefully using this information you'll feel informed enough to make your own choices (or propose an alternative answer I'd love to read)